# database relationship line isn't show on datadrip and phpmyadim

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, mariadb, datagrip

I'm developing an app and a draw the entire database( relationship, set forein keys and so on), I'm using mysql as databas server, until here it all ok, but when trying to visualize the database the relationships lines is not showing, all I see is the tables but about the reference keys for relationship seems all good, please I would like that you guys help me to fix it.

[image]

I'm posting the database image from datagrip

Comment: If you create a very simple new database with two tables, is it the same? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2715

Comment: i'll do it to see @moscas

Comment: yes it still showing the same problem

Comment: Please share DDL of this "simple" example

Comment: Thanks @moscas but i already solved it has you can see bellow in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for the helps, i'm using wamp server and for same unkwon reason for me it's set engine=MYISAM as default engine default and after ready this issue https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_change_the_database_engine_of_a_mysql_database_table/

i was looking a way to fix it and i did the following steps on wampserver:

1 º left click on wampserver icon > mysql > my.in (click on that)
2 º on my.in > ctrl+l > paste this on input field : default-storage-engine=MYISAM > press enter 
3 º if find  changes it's value to default-storage-engine=innodb 
4 º save the my.in file and enjoy,

i hope it can help others ........

down i'm posting the images to see that is all okay now for me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cltVc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVu0Y.png)

Comment: You would need to `ALTER` each table to change from MyISAM to InnoDB.  And you need InnoDB to make use of `FOREIGN KEYs`.